# Lighting isn't consistent on a flat surface on mesh

Tags: materials, lighting

As the title says, when I am trying to render an object, in a border of two faces, lighting gets completely different and it gets a lot brighter. I think a picture explains it better so I just put it here and give more details based on that picture.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see on the bottom left viewport, there is a noticeable seam on the object and the brightness changes on different sides of the seam, while it shouldn't
Other information I can give:

- There is actually a UV seam there, because the wood on the top has a different orientation than sides and I had to rotate UVs for that.
- There is only one unique material for the object, so the material doesn't change on faces
- I plugged the texture into a Hue/Saturation node to make some adjustments, but then directly plugged it onto the base color input on Principled Shader node.
- The texture I've used is visible at the bottom right section. And as you see, there's no brightness variation on the texture. I've even tried putting the UVs on top of each other so they get the same texture but it didn't help the brightness
- The surface of the object is completely flat
- I am using an hdri for lighting, which is just a sky with a single source of light
- The normals are facing the right direction

Here's the link to the .blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Erlzgh5aJCaZJdDroysTKxtML7Z1PGjY/view?usp=sharing

And here's the hdri used for lighting:

https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=high%20contrast&h=rooitou_park

Textures are licensed and I can't share them, but the problem still exists without the textures.

I tried to cover everything I saw necessary, but if I missed a piece of information, please tell me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As a fix, I assigned a duplicate of the same material to the brighter part, and just fixed its brightness through a Hue/Saturation node. It works, but I think there are better solutions to that. And the question of why that happens is still not answered.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It's hard to say from these images, but you can [share your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a closer look.

Comment: Have you checked that the normals point in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I checked normal directions and they were facing the right direction. And I'll update the post with .blend file now, I couldn't upload it to the website you shared so I just uploaded it to Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Check your shader graph. In the *Image Texture* node for Normals, check if your color expression is set to *Non-Color*. Changing it from *sRGB* to *Non-Color* fixed the issue for me.